# Copy specific range from multiple workbooks into one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do something similar to what is asked in the question for **VBA: Copy specific range from multiple workbooks into one worksheet** but with a slight variation. I am trying to get a single cell value (AB26) from mutliple workbooks and combine them into a single master workbook in a single column. This is what I am working with in terms of code:

```
Sub CopyRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Const strPath As String = "\\OTLAN1\USERDATA\BCAS\CTCAC\2020\2020 E-Apps\Old E-Apps\"
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
    'locate last row to start copying new value from the next spreadsheet
        LastRow = .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'From the Basis & Credits cell AB46, copy to last row+1 in the Master sheet starting in row A2
        .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB46" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub
```

I can't seen to get this to run though. Whenever it starts, the macro runs through and then the developer opens back up with nothing done and no errors.

Comment: I would do `strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")` rather than using `ChDir`.

Comment: Why do you need `LastRow ` since you say that you only want copying range "AB26"?

Comment: I am using the `LastRow` code so that the value from cell AB46 from each workbook print in the next row down instead of overwriting the value in the same cell each time.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is on this line

```
.Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB46" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Change the range to copy from `Range("AB46" & LastRow)` to `Range("AB" & LastRow)` i.e. remove the `46` and the line will become

```
.Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

I suspect you are currently copying cell AB4626 which is most likely empty.

Comment: Good catch. It's confusing whether OP wants to determine the last cell, or just use the hard-coded 46.... either way, you describe what's currently happening.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, and the question actually mentioned AB26. Anyway, I hope this pin-pointed a bug in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue that I initially was having was due to the fact that I was missing the PasteSpecial function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy from AB26, try the next code, please:

```
Sub CopyRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wkbDest As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long

strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
       'locate last row to start copying new value from the next spreadsheet
        LastRow = wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
        'From the Basis & Credits cell AB46, copy to last row+1 in the Master sheet starting in row A2
        .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB26").Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRow)
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But if you need to copy from "AB46" like is written in the code comment, you must, of course, change `Range("AB26").Copy` with `Range("AB46").Copy` ...

Comment: I was able to get the code above to work for what I need. However, there are some files that are run through the kick out a runtime error 1004 due to what I assume is related to the fact that the value that I am copying from is in a merged field. If I remove the workbook in question from the directory, the code runs through the rest of the workbooks fine. Is there a way to build an error handler that skips the impacted workbook and provides a printout of the workbook name so they can be manually addressed?

Comment: @JosephD: When you are talking about an error, it would be necessary to specify at which code line appears... Does it appear on the line `.Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB26").Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRow)'? If yes, I will adapt the code to send a message telling the workbook name and let the code continuing.